# For the function f and contour C, use parametric representations for C to evaluate the contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)= 1$ when $y<0$ and $f(z)=4y$ when $y>0$. C is the arc from $z=-1-i$ to $z=1+i$ along the curve $y=x^3$. Calculate the contour integral $\int_C f(z)dz$

I feel like I am so close but can't get the right answer of $2+3i$. I don't see why this isn't just $\int_{-1}^0 1dx+\int_0^1 4x^3dx$. The first integral has to be 1 right since that's what $f(z)$ is for that interval? I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try using the fact that $$\int_{C}f(z)dz=\int_{-1}^1(f\circ \gamma)(t)\gamma'(t)dt$$ where $$\gamma(t)=t+it^3:t\in[-1,1]$$

Comment: @MatthewH. Got it thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a function $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ s.t $g(t)=u(t)+iv(t)$ the definition of the integral over $[a,b]$ of $g$ is
$$
\intop_a^b g(t)dt=\intop_a^b u(t)dt+i\cdot\intop_a^b v(t)dt
$$
where the RHS are real riemann integrals.

Now, for a  continuously differentiable curve $\gamma  :[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ and a function $f(z)$ that is continuous on $\gamma$, the definition of the contour integral of $f$ on $\gamma$ is
$$
\intop_\gamma f(z)dz=\intop_a^b f(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t)dt
$$

In our case, $\gamma(t)=t+it^3,\;\;-1\le t\le1$ and $f(z)=\begin{cases} 1, & \Im(z)<0\\ 4\cdot\Im(z), & \Im(z)\geq0
\end{cases}$

So we will get
$$
\begin{align}
\intop_\gamma f(z)dz & =\intop_{-1}^1 f(\gamma(t))\cdot(1+3it^2)dt=\intop_{-1}^0 1+3it^2dt+\intop_0^1 4\cdot t^3\cdot(1+3it^2)dt\\
& [t+it^3]_{-1}^0+[t^4+2it^6]_0^1=1+i+1+2i=2+3i
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

It's a line integral, so you have too take into account the changes in both directions.

$dx/dt=1$. $dy/dt=3t^2$

$dz=(dx/dt)+i(dy/dt)$

$\int_{-1}^0(1)(1+i3t^2)dt+\int_0^1(4t^3)(1+i3t^2)dt=(1+i)+(1+2i)=2+3i$

Despite $f(z)$ always being real, $\int f(z) dz$ can still have an imaginary part.